# Retain Cycle in Swift delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, retain-cycle

I have a `UIViewController` and in it a `UIToolbar`. They get instantiated from a storyboard.

I made a custom class for my `UIToolbar`. Based on some logic I do or do not show buttons on it.

The `UIViewController` needs to take action when some of the buttons are tapped.
For this I created a delegate protocol in the `UIToolbar`.

Currently, when I dismiss the view, it is kept in memory. Further investigation revealed my delegate created a retain cycle.

In Objective-C, we would simply define delegates as `weak`. However, I am using Swift, and it does not allow me to define `delegate` variable as `weak`:

```
weak var navigationDelegate: MainToolBarDelegate?
// 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type 'MainToolBarDelegate'
```

When I dismiss the view controller, I set `self.toolBar.navigationDelegate = nil` and the memory gets cleared. But it feels wrong!

Why do I get the retain cycle and why can I not simply define the delegate as `weak`?

Comment: Is your NavigationDelegate a protocol (as opposed to a [class-only protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281)?) If it's just a standard protocol, there's no guarantee that your actual object will be a class instance rather than a structure, hence "Cannot be applied to non-class type"; if it could be a structure or an enum, then it can't be `weak`, as it might not be a reference type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`weak` references only apply to classes, not structs or enums, which are value types. But protocols by default can apply to any of those types.

Define your `MainToolBarDelegate` as a class-only protocol:

```
protocol MainToolBarDelegate: AnyObject {

}
```

Then you'll be able to declare your delegate as `weak`.

Comment: do you know if there is any difference between using : class or : NSObjectProtocol

Comment: @user2363025 `class` means any class, and `NSObjectProtocol` means anything that conforms to this protocol. I would use `class` unless you have a specific reason to use `NSObjectProtocol`.